# Windows command prompt capture output of bash script in one step

Tags: linux, windows, bash, shell, command-prompt

I trigger a bash script from Windows command prompt.

```
postCloneSetup.sh
```

It opens another window and then returns. The window it spawned stays open and logs output text.

[image]

I want to capture the output from the spawned window and return that to the Windows command prompt.

I would prefer to use something like

```
$(postCloneSetup.sh) // Linux for capturing output to current context
```

for the Windows command prompt.

I'd prefer not to modify postCloneSetup.sh. I know I could have it write out to a file with

```
exec &> postCloneSetupLog.log
```

but then I must wait and manually run

```
type postCloneSetupLog.log
```

to see the output in the console. This is not possible for integrating into a CI engine, which is my goal.

**How can I capture the output from the spawned console in one command?**

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. If you feel its on-topic elsewhere, then [ask for a migration](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)

Comment: Ok, migrated to [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1218943/windows-command-prompt-capture-output-of-bash-script-in-one-step).